# magento enterprise to community downgrade, will customer login work after migration?

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer, magento-community, login

If I am downgrading from magento enterprise to community edition, will the existing customer login work, as it is in community edition without any change? or will it require to reset the password for all the users?

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked before over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643618/) as a programming question on how to convert, and **Indications say no**

And the conclusion is since you have access to the Enterprise code, build your own module to convert CE to use the Enterprise password hash algorithm.

They are hashes, so they cannot be decrypted. And the possible difference is Enterprise salts before hashing and storing. A quick scan of the code shows them to both use MD5 for the hash algorithm.

Answer (score -3):

The downgrade should work, and customers do not need to reset there passwords as the customer part of the enterprise code is based on the community (Mage_Customer). You will only need to change the templates where you use Enterprise functions.

Comment: A different encoding is used for customer password in EE. You have to take that into account.

Comment: Has been done before, the logins did not work. The question was about de-encrypting the passwords stored by EE and re-encrypting them with the CE function, an operation not possible because passwords are stored as a one-way hash.